# Doctrine thinks it has created a table, but it hasn't

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am following the "Getting Started with Doctrine" simple, short tutorial
([here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) )

At some point, there is the following conversation between
Doctrine and me :

```
ewandelanoy$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql
CREATE TABLE products (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ewandelanoy$
```

So it seems that things works correctly ; when I go look into
my database with phpAdmin however, I find that the table
has not been created.
And indeed, I get error messages when I try to continue with
the tutorial and use that table.

How can I "debug Doctrine" in this situation ?
It seems that Doctrine fails to connect to the database ?

So here are my configuration details :

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$paths = array("src/");
$isDevMode = false;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'dbname'   => 'flea_database',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your dump really create the schema, you have to use :

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql --force
```

The `--dump-sql` shows you the query, the `--force` execute it really.

Run the command without options for more informations.

See the [Tools part of doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#command-overview)

Comment: It works, now I see my table in phpMyAdmin. Thanks for answering my stupid question